# Замена текста в EditBox'е без выделения этого текста

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Как можно заменить часть текста в EditBox'е со стилем ES_MULTILINE без выделения этого текста? Сейчас делаю через EM_SETSEL и EM_REPLACESEL, но при выделении текста окно EditBox'а скролится к выделению, что мне не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Получить весь текст в строку через `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`, `WM_GETTEXT`
2. Отредактировать строку
3. Записать строку обратно через `WM_SETTEXT`

Comment: Тоже самое - скачет скролл.

Comment: @АлександрПатейчук A если дернуть `LockWindowUpdate` или `BeginPaint`?

Comment: Тоже не помогает